# Integer.ValueOf radix 16

Tags: java

```
public class Test { 

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Integer b = Integer.valueOf("444",16);

       System.out.println(b);
    }

}
```

Why does this code print `1092`?

Comment: 1092 is the decimal equivalent of hexadecimal 444

Comment: @AxelH I felt this way it is easier if someone else is searching for the same issue

Comment: I agree @pvpkiran, your title is much better but then move the question in the body ;) A post without a question is a bad question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Default `valueOf` assumes base 10. If you specify it as

```
Integer.valueOf("444",16);
```

This is like saying base 16. This translates to 1092 like this

4*16² + 4*16¹ + 4*16⁰

4*16*16 + 4*16 + 4  = 1092

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) for the `valueOf()` method:

> Returns an Integer object holding the value extracted from the specified String when parsed with the radix given by the second argument.

Radix 16 is hexadecimal, and the decimal equivalent of `444` is `1092` ([source)](https://www.hexdictionary.com/hex/444)